# bootstrap 3 navbar collapse -> another menus don't collapse

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

Here is my html:

```
<div id="MainMenu">
                <div class="list-group panel nav nav-sidebar">
                    <a href="#menu1" class="list-group-item list-group-item-success" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#MainMenu"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Barang</a>
                    <div class="collapse" id="menu1">
                        <a class="level2 list-group-item " href="">Masukkan Barang</a>
                        <a class="level2 list-group-item active" href="">Daftar Barang</a>
                    </div>
                    <a href="#menu2" class="list-group-item list-group-item-success" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#MainMenu"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Stok</a>
                    <div class="collapse" id="menu2">
                        <a class="level2 list-group-item " href="">Stok Opname</a>
                        <a class="level2 list-group-item " href="">Daftar Stok</a>
                    </div>
                    <a href="#menu3" class="list-group-item list-group-item-success" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#MainMenu"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Transaksi</a>
                    <div class="collapse" id="menu3">
                        <a class="level2 list-group-item " href="">Penjualan</a>
                        <a class="level2 list-group-item " href="">Daftar Nota</a>
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
            </div>
```

Here is my JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.collapse').on('show.bs.collapse', function() {
    $(this).prev().find(".glyphicon").removeClass("glyphicon-plus").addClass("glyphicon-minus");
});
$('.collapse').on('hide.bs.collapse', function() {
    $(this).prev().find(".glyphicon").removeClass("glyphicon-minus").addClass("glyphicon-plus");
});
$(".collapse").has('a.active').collapse('show');});
```

i have attached jquery 2.0 and bootstrap.js,
when i click menu2 (or other) then click menu1 which has .active, menu2 doesn't collapse but menu1 shows well. Another menus work fine except menu1 which has .active.
Please anybody help me.

here is my fiddle:
[collapse with active menu](http://jsfiddle.net/DnNPH/)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try removing this line in code, and check. Hope it works fine.

```
 $(".collapse").has('a.active').collapse('show');
```

Comment: hi karthikeyan,
thanks for response.
ya, that works fine.
but, how can i get the active menu open when the page loaded?